# make dictionary to objects of class in python

Tags: python, design-patterns

i made the class for making dict keys to object accessor but this is not working in nested case

```
d= {'c': {'v': {'a'}}, 'e': 'x', 'r': 'e'}
class A:
     def __init__(self, dicti):
         self.__dict__.update(dicti)
o = A(d)
# i want something like o.c.v=a , o.e=x, o.r=e
# i'm unable to make nested dict object accessor
```

looking for help

Comment: Creating a class for this adds unnecessary complexity to your code. Any reason why you don't want to access `d['c']['v']` other than you want a class?

Comment: Also, note how you're reworking the class **dict** from an existing dict: your class is fundamentally a dict with super powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to traverse the structure, creating a series of nested class `A` objects:

```
d= {'c': {'v': {'a'}}, 'e': 'x', 'r': 'e'}
class A:
  def __init__(self, dicti):
     self.__dict__ = {a:A(b) if isinstance(b, dict) else b for a, b in dicti.items()}

a = A(d)
print(a.c.v)
print(a.r)
```

Output:

```
{'a'}
'e'
```